# How to prove $\mu(\mathbb{R^n})=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

**Question:** If $U \subsetneq \mathbb R^n$ , $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ supported on $U$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is a non-zero real-valued symmetric function. We denote $d\mu(x)=\hat{f}(x)dx$ where $\hat{f}$ is $f$ Fourier transform. I want to prove $\mu(\mathbb R^n)=0$ but I cannot prove it.

I think this conclusion is correct. If I consider $n=1$ and $ f=|x|, |x| \le 1$, then we have $$\hat{f}(x)=\int_{-1}^{1} e^{ixy} |y| dy=2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\right).$$
Hence I obtain $$\mu(\mathbb R)=\int_{\mathbb R}\hat{f}(x)dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx=\pi -\pi=0.$$
I hope you can give some suggestions, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It looks like you are taking an inverse Fourier transform at the point $x=0$. But you would need more structure.  For example what if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mbox{if $x=0$}\\1 & \mbox{if $x \in [-1, 0)\cup (0, 1]$} \\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ The discontinuity at $0$ does not affect any integral.

Comment: if $n=1$ the statement is clearly false as every function is trivially symmetric

Comment: You must have more hypotheses on $f$...

Comment: For example, are you given that $f$ is continuous? Integrable?